# How to compute this probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

A drawer contains eight different pairs of socks. If six socks are drawn at random and without replacement, how to compute the probability that there is at least one matching pair among these six socks?

I know that my desired probability equals $1$ minus the probability of the event that there is not a single matching pair.

But now how to compute this latter probability?

Comment: Something like $1-{14 \over 15} {12 \over 14} {10 \over 13} {8 \over 12} {6 \over 11}$?

Comment: copper.hat, I'm afraid I didn't get you. Did you mean $1 - \frac{14}{16}\frac{12}{14}\frac{10}{12}\frac{8}{10}\frac{6}{8}\frac{4}{6}= 1-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$?

Answer (score 4):

Compute the probability of the opposite event, then subtract the result from $1$:

- The number of ways to choose $6$ pairs out of $8$ pairs is $\dbinom{8}{6}=28$
- The number of ways to choose one sock from each one of $6$ pairs is $2^6=64$
- The number of ways to choose $6$ socks out of $8$ pairs is $\dbinom{16}{6}=8008$
- So the probability of the opposite event is $\dfrac{28\cdot64}{8008}=\dfrac{224}{1001}$
- So the probability of the actual event is $1-\dfrac{224}{1001}=\dfrac{777}{1001}$

Comment: barak manos, could you please justify the product in the numerator in your calculation of the probability of the opposite event?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: You are choosing $6$ out of $16$ socks. You need to count all those groups of $6$ socks where no $2$ socks make a pair. So you first choose $6$ pairs. Then, from each pair you can choose either one of $2$ socks. Thus, in order to calculate the number of different combinations, you multiply the results. Does that make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Let's compute the probability $q$ that you don't get a matching pair.

We are picking the socks one after the other. After the first sock has been picked there remain $15$ socks, and $14$ of these are "allowed". After two picks with no matching pair there remain $14$ socks, and $12$ of these are "allowed", and so on. It follows that the probability $q$ for $6$ "allowed" picks in a row is given by
$$q={16\over16}\cdot{14\over15}\cdot{12\over14}\cdot{10\over13}\cdot{8\over12}\cdot{6\over11}={32\over143}\ .$$
The probability $p$ that we obtain at least one matching pair in $\leq6$ picks then comes to
$$p=1-q={111\over143}\doteq0.776\ .$$